# Associate colors with points in ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: graphics3d

This doesn't work. Should I use slot?

```
(* coordinates *)
a = {1, 1, 0.1};
b = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};

(* colors *)
ca = {1, 0, 1};
cb = {0, 1, 0};

ListPointPlot3D[{a, b}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{a, b}, RGBColor[{ca, cb}]]]
```

Comment: Why not use `Style[]`? `ListPointPlot3D[{Style[{1, 1, 0.1}, RGBColor[1, 0, 1]], Style[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]}]`

Comment: You could do `ListPointPlot3D[List /@ {a, b}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor /@ {ca, cb}]`. Usually I just end up going straight to `Graphics3D` and plotting points, e.g. `Graphics3D[
 {PointSize[0.02], RGBColor[#2], Point[#1]} & @@@ 
  Transpose@{{a, b}, {ca, cb}}, Axes -> True]`. I find it easier to control as I start asking for more customization.

Comment: That works for me. Thanks!